# Display way too small results in R

Tags: r, exponential

Sometimes, I will have to estimate the exponential notation(here, I mean to estimate b of `a*e^b`) of a number way too small. For example,

```
> 1-pnorm(30)
[1] 0
```

Because the result is too small, I tried `options()` with parameters `scipen` and `digits` and failed. Neither tweaks worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just avoid using `1-pnorm':

```
pnorm(30,lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 4.906714e-198
```